# Django-haystack undefined function

Tags: django, django-urls, django-haystack

on this line of code in views.py for my app i get this error

```
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'))

NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```

I think 'haystack.urls' is somehow not being included in my database but am not sure how to figure out if my hunch is correct. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not related with haystack. If you are new in django world, and you want to use haystack, I think this material could be useful for you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-n6_m66TmA - Python Django Tutorial 21 - Full text search with haystack and whoosh (there are other earlier episodes), and demo with haystack and (more powerful, but more complicated solr): https://github.com/broderboy/django-solr-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python can't find the `include` function (thus the message that `include` is not defined. You must import it like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
```

Comment: What if you don't use Django? Where is import declared then?